# Error when trying to implement Header in a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, export-to-csv

I have successfully exported the data I receive from the rows I read into a csv file, but I need to set a Header for each row so I can identify them. I have tried this:

```
file = open("llistaClients.csv", "w")
file.write("ID;NAME;PHONE;EMAIL;STREET;CITY")
for row in rows:        
    print(row['id'], row['name'], row['phone'], row['email'], row['street'], row['city'], sep="\t")
    dades = str(row['id']) + ";" + str(row['name']) + ";" + str(row['phone']) + ";" + str(row['email']) \
            + ";" + str(row['street']) + ";" + str(row['city']);
    file.write(dades + "\n")
```

Without this `file.write("ID;NAME;PHONE;EMAIL;STREET;CITY")` it all works perfectly:

[image]

But if I try to use it, it just won't open with Excel. But, if I open the same file with the notepad it indeed applies this header.

I have a potential fix which lets me put the header without problem using: (other fields)

```
    import csv

    with open("llistaProductes.csv","w") as csvfile:

    fieldnames = ['id','name','list_price','create_date'];
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader();
    for row in rows:
        #print(dict(row))
        print(row['id'], row['name'], row['list_price'], row['create_date'], sep="\t")
        writer.writerow({'id': row['id'], 'name': row['name'],
                         'list_price': row['list_price'], 'create_date': row['create_date']})
```

But using this I get this in excel:

[image]

It doesn't separate between columns.. Which is not bad, but not how it should do..

So the question here is, **why can't I use the first method properly? And if the second is the one I should use how to separate the columns.** Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you forgot the newline after your header: `file.write("ID;NAME;PHONE;EMAIL;STREET;CITY\n")`

Comment: Oh, I did try with it but didn't put it in the question. Not working with it either.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a newline after the header:

```
file.write("ID;NAME;PHONE;EMAIL;STREET;CITY\n")
```

I see no reason why Excel wouldn't open this file. Do you get an error message?

As for the second example, you can tell Excel to use a certain separator by adding the following in the beginning of the file:

```
sep=,
id,name,email, ..
```

Comment: Excel says the format and the extension of the file are not the same. It gives me the chance to discard and open, I do so and it gives me registry errors ( example: can't read registry 70). And then if I discard that, it won't let me open the file.

Comment: And the sep=, works with the command print, it's a utility print has, nothing to do with the csv stuff.

Comment: @Raül But the same file (with ; sep) opens fine without the header? Strange.

Comment: @Raül If Excel sees a sep=, (or sep=;) as the first line of the csv file it will (should) use that as the separator (though tehnically this is not 'standard' csv). Not sure what you mean with command/utility print.